# Any available algorithm for numerical feature selection in caret with r

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

I am using the following code (caret in r) to check the feature importance. An error of `wrong model type for regression` is reported. I found out that the method `lvq` is for categorical attributes, but what I have are all numerical variables. Is there any suggestion on an available algorithm or method for my case?

```
set.seed(7)
# load the library
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
# load the dataset
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
# prepare training scheme
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
# train the model
model <- train(diabetes~., data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, method="lvq", preProcess="scale", 
  trControl=control)
# estimate variable importance
importance <- varImp(model, scale=FALSE)
# summarize importance
print(importance)
# plot importance
plot(importance)
```

Comment: Take a look at [This tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-the-caret-r-package/)

Comment: Thanks for your commnet, G5W